# ABNF augmented by HTTP : normative reference for #symbol

Tags: http, specifications, abnf

#### Context

Solving a `CORS` issue, I was wondering what are the valid values for the HTTP response header `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`.

The Whatwg [CORS spec on header syntax](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#http-new-header-syntax) tells me in ABNF that :

> `Access-Control-Allow-Headers     = #field-name`

And the [RFC7230](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2) tells me that :

```
field-name     = token
token = 1*tchar
tchar = "!" / "#" / "$" / "%" / "&" / "'" / "*" / "+" / "-" / "." / "^" / "_" / "`" / "|" / "~" / DIGIT / ALPHA
```

In addition, [Whatwg states](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#abnf) that :

> ABNF means ABNF as augmented by HTTP (in particular the addition #) and RFC 7405. [RFC7405]

OK, I now know that this response header is invalid:

> `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, content type, Accept, Authorization`

field-name should not contain a white space, but this leads to my question :

#### Question

Where is the normative reference for `#symbol` in whatwg ABNF? It's not the the [RFC5234](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5234) defining the ABNF syntax. I guest it's something like a comma separated fields, but I did not find a real reference.

*PS: the question is not "What are the valid values for `Access-Control-Allow-Headers`"*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This *"as augmented by HTTP (in particular the addition #)"* comes from [RFC 7230 - Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP/1.1): Message Syntax and Routing section 7. ABNF List Extension: #rule](https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7230.html#abnf.extension):

> A #rule extension to the ABNF rules of [RFC5234] is used to improve
> readability in the definitions of some header field values.
>
> A construct "#" is defined, similar to "*", for defining
> comma-delimited lists of elements. The full form is "`<n>#<m>element`"
> indicating at least `<n>` and at most `<m>` elements, each separated by a
> single comma (",") and optional whitespace (OWS).
>
> In any production that uses the list construct, a sender must not
> generate empty list elements. In other words, a sender must generate
> lists that satisfy the following syntax:
>
> 1#element => element *( OWS "," OWS element )
>
> (...)

So `#field-name` becomes "zero or more `field-name` (separated by commas and surrounded by optional linear whitespace)", because n and m default to 0 and infinity, respectively.

Comment: True, but a more recent definition is in RFC 7230, Section 7. (<https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7230.html#abnf.extension>)

Comment: @Julian thanks, I've updated the answer, feel free to include more details.

Comment: Well done ! Did you knew the answer or did you searched it ? If you searched it, how did you searched ? I always kind of struggle when I query a SE with a request containing a special character.

Comment: @Gabriel I clicked your links and searched for related terms, ultimately ending up at RFC 2616 when searching "http abnf augmented #" or something like that. I don't use Stack Overflow's search, onsite search almost never works. I have to admit I've read all HTTP and related RFCs once or more for fun, so it rang a bell